# Lumen show different time than what is saved is MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, laravel, timezone, lumen

my current timezone is **Asia/Karachi** and when i retrieve table data from mysql it gives me (actual time - 5 hours)

for eg:

> mysql column value: '2021-04-21 01:34:57'

and when i retrieve from laravel DB::table('table_name')->get()->toArray();

> it gives following :2021-04-20 20:34:57

and changing my timezone doesn't change anything either.

so is there something else i'm missing ?

btw i created following route for checking my current timezone

> ```
> $app->get('/timezone', function () {
>     return date_default_timezone_get();
> });
> ```

and it gives same what is saved in my env i.e(Asia/Karachi) but this doesn't change the result i get from mysql even if i change it to some other timezone like Asia/Kolkata.

I tried researching on this but didn't get any suitable answer.

Comment: *mysql column value: '2021-04-21 01:34:57'* What is column datatype - DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: @Akina timestamp NOT NULL

Comment: If your column have TIMESTAMP datatype then the value was saved as GMT (more precisely the timezone of the stored value is assumed to be GMT during data retrieve). How you define that stored value is *'2021-04-21 01:34:57'*?

Comment: yes the stored value is "2021-04-21 01:34:57" but when its retrieved from lumen command it changes its time and date like mentioned above.

Comment: however the value in db stays put i.e 2021-04-21 01:34:57 when i check in my dbms

Comment: Try to select both original value of TIMESTAMP datatype and the value converted to string datatype (for example, by `CONCAT(column, '')`) in the same query - does the values differs?

Comment: in my dbms its showing everything fine the problem is with lumen i think. because lumen is changing the value otherwise same query runs fine in SQLYOG

Comment: If DBMS returns correct value then this is PHP "service" it seems...

Comment: yes indeed @akina its framework related

Comment: If so I can tell nothing - I don't use PHP.

Comment: its ok. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried alot of things to solve this issue like
adding env variables `APP_TIMEZONE="Asia/Karachi"` (did not work)
also i tried adding `DB_TIMEZONE="+05:00"` (this worked in my local but not on stagging)

finally i saw somewhere that someone else had exact same issue resolving this and he did it by adding the hours using carbon which also worked for me

```
'posted_at' => Carbon::parse($record->posted_at)->addHours(5)->toDateTimeString(),
```

i know this is not the optimal solution but this was the only solution that worked so i had to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

> If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for conversion in both directions. The current time zone is available as the value of the time_zone system variable.

As far as I know, you have a couple things to consider:

**The timezone of your Laravel/Lumen app**

This can be found found in `config/app.php` -> `timezone`.

**The timezone of your MySQL server**

You can retrieve this using:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

**The timezone of the server itself**

If the mySQL query above returns `SYSTEM`, it means it uses the system timezone setting, which for Debian/Ubuntu etc you can check using:

```
cat /etc/timezone
```

---

From my experience, you can most often leave the system/mySQL timezones intact and only set the correct timezone in your Laravel config. I know it caused me a headache the first time I had to figure out how this actually worked.

Comment: "If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored." 

this is not happening in my case and that's what i'm worried about.

Comment: which timezone have you tried changing? try the Lumen config file approach, it should work. Your date is simply being converted to a different timezone in your Lumen app which is my guess

Comment: actually i have tried changing my timezone (i.e through env file as well as from app.php file) and it did change the timezone but that did not affect the result at all. i was getting same  -5 hour result as before.

Answer (score 0):

I set DB_TIMEZONE="Europe/Tallinn" and everything worked